# How does one go about finding a distribution for this property of the distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am told I need to find a probability distribution in which this Chebyshev Inequality is fulfilled: $P(|X-\mu|\ge 5\sigma)=.04$. What I tried was just taking a simple distribution where the support is just $0$ and $1$ and then playing with the probabilities, but I just couldn't get it. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** It is a little more complicated than a Bernoulli, but not much more. Try the random variable $X$ with the following distribution:
$$\Pr(X=-1)=\Pr(X=1)=\frac{1}{50},\qquad\Pr(X=0)=\dfrac{48}{50}.$$

**Added:** We do the calculation. By symmetry $\mu=0$. Calculate the variance of $X$. This is $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$, but since $E(X)=\mu=0$ it is just $E(X^2)$.

Note that $X^2=0$ with probability $\frac{48}{50}$, and $1$ with probability $\frac{1}{50}+\frac{1}{50}=\frac{1}{25}$. Thus $E(X^2)=\frac{1}{25}$, so $\sigma^2=\frac{1}{25}$ and therefore $\sigma=\frac{1}{5}$. Thus $5\sigma=1$.

Finally, $\Pr(|X-\mu|\ge 5\sigma=\Pr(|X|\ge 1)=\frac{1}{50}+\frac{1}{50}=\frac{1}{25}=0.04$.

Comment: how would I show that the probability equals four? Also what made you pick this distribution?

Comment: There was an error earlier, slipped a decimal point. Calculation is now done in detail. As I had mentioned in an earlier comment, the $|X-\mu|$ part kind of forces a symmetrical example. Looking at this sort of example is natural in view of the argument for the Chebyshev Inequality, and I have proved the result many times in lectures.

Comment: If one looks at the proof of Chebyshev inequality trying to make inequalities equalities, one sees that this distribution is the only solution (with its affine transforms).